# Trying to get vimpager (to replace less) working with nerdTREE

Tags: vim

I'm trying to get switch over to vim as my primary editor and I've installed the nerdTree plugin, but now when I try and use vimpager to replace less I get

```
Error detected while processing VimEnter Auto commands for "*":
E492: Not an editor command: NERDTree
```

I've narrowed it down to this line in my `.vimrc`, but I don't know much about configuring vim, I got this `.vimrc` off the internet.

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
```

My best guess is that vimpager is trying to disable plugin, but the `.vimrc` is trying to load it, so they're getting an error.

Any advise on resolving this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447334/how-do-you-add-nerdtree-to-your-vimrc/5763243

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct fix is to move

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
```

out of your `~/.vimrc` and into `~/.vim/after/plugin/NERD_tree.vim`.

That way, the autocmd only gets run if NERD_tree has also been loaded.

And to be more correct, you should probably make it

```
if exists("loaded_nerd_tree")
    echo 'loaded_nerd_tree' . loaded_nerd_tree
endif
```

that way if the plugin is uninstalled, your `after` script won't still try to use the plugin.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I put 
 `autocmd VimEnter * NERDTreeerd_tree`
 `autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p` 
inside the if instead though. Otherwise when I start vim I need to press enter to continue